# Windows : What happens to the UI when the app is minimized?

Tags: windows, windows-11, windows-package-manager

I was wondering what will happen to the UI when the app is minimized. Will it refresh the UI [With respect to its content] even when the app is minimized?

In the thumbnail[ When we hover on the app icon in taskbar ] we cant see apps UI being refreshed when app is minimized, but we can see the UI being refreshed in thumbnail when app goes to background and new app comes on the foreground.

What I think is, when the app is minimized, the UI thread/Main thread will keep updating the apps UI [depending on the content], but the changes will not be rendered on the screen. the changes will be stacked on a buffer and when the app is brought up, top of the buffer is rendered. Is this right?

It would be of great help if you can help me get a detailed understanding in it.

Thank you